# How to use struct to read from file?

Tags: python, struct

I need to simulate data stream(it can be reading from file) in the form of packages (struct in python is the proposed idea) which contain neccessary data about the package.
Lets say the file is made of 2 types uint32 each taking 4 bytes.
I have to send  3 bytes I want to split him on 2-bytes packages. So I have 1 package containing 2 bytes and the second one containing 1 byte. To be easier we can assume the file is made of (255)DEC=(FF)HEX. So it would like like that in HEX:(First uint is package number, and the second package size) 
Package1: 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 FF FF
Package2: 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 FF
In theory I understand it, but it's pretty hard to find solution in python code for it, I've created test package with value and string, but to be honest I have no idea how to get the values from files instead of hardcoding?

```
    import struct
    class Packet:
        def __init__(self, value=111, data=b'string'):
            self.value = value
            self.data = data
            self.raw = None


        def pack(self):
            self.raw = struct.pack('is', self.value, self.data)
            return
```

To make it clear it the cpp code which I really need to implement in python:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

#pragma pack(push,1)
typedef struct {
      int i;
      char a[20];   
} Structp1;

typedef struct {
      int i;
      char a[21];   
} Structp2;
#pragma pack(pop)



//not compressed

typedef struct {
      int i;
      char a[20];   
} Struct1;

typedef struct {
      int i;
      char a[21];   
} Struct2;



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int length;
  char * buffer;
  char aa[20];       
  char aa1[21];           
  fstream stream;
  StrukturaP1 SP1;


  cout << "                        rozmiar w bajtach" << endl;
  cout << "struct 1 uncompressed   = " << sizeof(Struct1)<<endl;    
  cout << "Struktura 1 compressed      = " << sizeof(Structp1)<<endl;      
  cout << "Struktura 2 uncompressed = " << sizeof(Struct2)<<endl;      
  cout << "Struktura 2 compressed= " << sizeof(Structp2)<<endl;      
//--------------------------------------------------------------------


//Open file for binary
  stream.open ("test.txt", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);
// Length so we put the pointer at the end
  stream.seekg (0, ios::end);
//get the size of the file
  length = stream.tellg();
// go back to start
  stream.seekg (0, ios::beg);

// allocate memory
  buffer = new char [length];

// read data from file
  stream.read (buffer,length);

  stream.close();
//print output
  cout.write (buffer,length);
//free memory
  delete[] buffer;

  stream.open ("test.bin", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);  
//cast on (char *) 
  cout << endl << "Reading to bin" << endl;
  stream.read ((char *)&SP1,sizeof(SP1));
//binary hex(01 00 00 00)
  cout << SP1.i << endl;
  cout << SP1.a << endl;

//save struct 2 now (Struct2p)
  SP1.i = 333;
//needs to use C string class 
  strcpy( SP1.a , "dddddd"); 

  stream.seekg (0, ios::end);
  stream.write ((char *)&SP1,sizeof(SP1));  
  if (stream.fail()) {
            cout << "Writing error"<<endl;      
  }
  stream.close();  

  system("PAUSE");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `data = open(filename, 'rb').read()` ? It reads in bytes mode all data and later you can pack it - but I don't know if I understand problem (PL: nie wiem czy rozumie problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand problem but to get data from file you need only read it in bytes mode `b`

```
data = open(filename, 'rb').read()
```

and later you have to pack data - and then you need `struct` - ie.

```
import struct

class Packet:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def stream(self):
        for number, idx in enumerate(range(0, len(self.data), 2) ,1):
            data = self.data[idx:idx+2]
            s = '>ii{}s'.format(len(data))
            # `s` will be '>ii2s' or `'>ii1s'
            yield struct.pack(s, number, len(data), data)

#data = open('.bashrc', 'rb').read()
#data = b'Hello World!'
data = b'abc'  # 3 bytes to have packets with size 2 and 1

p = Packet(data=data)

for item in p.stream():
    print(item)
```

---

**EDIT:** Base on new C code it could be something like this

```
import struct

structp1_format = 'i20s'
structp1_lenght = struct.calcsize(structp1_format)

structp2_format = 'i21s'
structp2_lenght = struct.calcsize(structp2_format)

struct1_format = 'i20s'
struct1_lenght = struct.calcsize(struct1_format)

struct2_format = 'i21s'
struct2_lenght = struct.calcsize(struct2_format)

def main():

  print("Size in bytes")
  print("Structure 1 uncompressed =", struct1_lenght)
  print("Structure 1 compressed   =", structp1_lenght)
  print("Structure 2 uncompressed =", struct2_lenght)
  print("Structure 2 compressed   =", structp2_lenght)

  #--------------------------------------------------------------------

  stream = open("test.txt", 'rb')
  
  #stream.seek(0, 2)
  #length = stream.tell()
  #stream.seek(0, 0)
  
  buffer = stream.read()
  length = len(buffer)
  
  stream.close()

  print(buffer)
  
  #del buffer

  #--------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  stream = open("test.bin", 'rb+');  

  print("Reading")
  
  buffer = stream.read(structp1_lenght)
  data = struct.unpack(structp1_format, buffer)  

  print('int:', data[0]) # int
  print('str:', data[1].decode()) # char[20]
  
  data = (333, "dddddd".encode())

  print("Writing")

  stream.seek(0, 0)
  
  buffer = struct.pack(structp1_format, data[0], data[1])

  try:
     stream.write(buffer)
  except Exception as ex:
     print('Ex:', ex)

  stream.close()

  input("PAUSE (press ENTER)")

main()
```

Python uses normal tuple `data[0]`, `data[1]` instead of structure `SP.i`, `SP.a`. Maybe using class `struct.Struct()` or normal `class` (or `namedtuple`) it could be use `SP.i`, `SP.a`

```
import struct

class SP:
    
    def __init__(self, i=0, a=b''):
        self.format = 'i20s'
        self.i = i
        self.a = a
        self.length = struct.calcsize(self.format)
        
    def pack(self):
        return struct.pack(self.format, self.i, self.a)
    
    def unpack(self, data):
        self.i, self.a = struct.unpack(self.format, data)
        
def main():

  sp = SP()
  
  # ---
  
  print('--- OPEN ---')

  stream = open("test.bin", 'rb+');  

  # ---
  
  print('--- READ ---')
  
  buffer = stream.read(sp.length)
  sp.unpack(buffer)  

  print('int:', sp.i) # int
  print('str:', sp.a.decode()) # char[20]
  
  # ---
  
  print('--- SEEK ---')

  stream.seek(0, 0)
  
  # ---
  
  print('--- WRITE ---')

  sp.i = 339
  sp.a = "dddddd".encode()

  buffer = sp.pack()
  stream.write(buffer)

  # ---
  
  print('--- CLOSE ---')

  stream.close()

  #input("PAUSE (press ENTER)")

main()
```

I put more versions (with `namedtuples`, `struct.Struct`, own class, etc.) on GitHub:
[furas/python-examples/struct/read-write-file](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/struct/read-write-file)

Comment: Thats pretty close to what I mean, because I dont know if I can explain it correctly, lets use my 'primary' programming language so I can show what do I want to do in python instead of using c++. I've edited my post and inserted the code.

Comment: I converted  C++ to Python.

Comment: line 47, in main
    data = struct.unpack(structp1_format, buffer)
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 24 bytes   Also is there any possibility to lets say read the data into single memory block, then slice it into as many pieces as you want and every slice will have its own id+size+contains the data inside?

Comment: `buffer` is normal list so you can read all at once and later slice it `buffer[start:end]`. If you have shorter data then (after reading data to `buffer`) you may have to use `len(buffer)` to create `struct_format`  with different value instead of `20`. ie. `struct_format = 'i{}s'.format(len(buffer)-4)`. OR read only `int`, unpack only `int` to create `struct_format` only for chars.

Comment: I don't really get it, I mean i understand the "data manipulation", but have no idea how to fix the struct.error.

Comment: if you have 24 bytes then you use `i20s` to unpack it. But if you will get 23 bytes then you have to use `i19s`. If you will get 22 bytes then you have to use `i18s`, etc. You can't use `i20s` if you have less then 24 bytes because it will give `struct.error`.

Comment: Yeah finally I understood with Your example: struct_format = 'i{}s'.format(len(buffer)-4), thanks, you are awesome man.